# Displaying statistical result in a GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, statistics, lifelines

I have a dataset and perform kaplan meier analysis on it using lifelines library, I then perform log rank and cox analysis, but the output i receieve are type 'statistical result' I would live to display this on a GUI but cannot figure it out.

Comment: This is very generic.  there are a number of GUI's available as well as a number of other methods (excel / pdf / web). Do you have something specific in mind, or what have you tried so far ?

Comment: My GUI is on python tkinter,but put this aside for a second, I perform the logrank analysis on my data and achieve a statistical result, its not an image, data frame or anything that I am able to download but rather just type 'statistical result' I need to display this on my GUI and not just in the python command line.

Comment: what do you mean `"statistical result"` ? If you means text then you can use `Label` or `Textbox` to display it. If you means some data in rows and columns then you could use `grid()` to put `Labels` in rows and columns.

Comment: The lifelines library has a type called 'statistical result'

Comment: @JacobMendelowitz you can access the properties of the `StatisticalResult` with a `.`. `result.p_value` for example

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data as a `csv` file.

From this, a (or any) package like `tkinter` can read the CSV.

Here is a stackoverflow link to such:

[How to show csv file in a grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748343/how-to-show-csv-file-in-a-grid)

And here is an example of the code:

```
import tkinter
import csv

root = tkinter.Tk()

# open file
with open("test.csv", newline = "") as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file)

   # r and c tell us where to grid the labels
   r = 0
   for col in reader:
      c = 0
      for row in col:
         # i've added some styling
         label = tkinter.Label(root, width = 10, height = 2, \
                               text = row, relief = tkinter.RIDGE)
         label.grid(row = r, column = c)
         c += 1
      r += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Obviously, you would need to apply your variant to this.